# Error using crossroads.js in optimized (r.js) require setup

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, r.js, crossroadsjs

I have developed an application using [**RequireJS**](http://requirejs.org), with no optimization layer - Require downloads each file separately. Here is the outer markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       var require = {
         //some basic config
       };
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <!--snip-->
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" data-main="main" src="scripts/lib/require.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

This functions without any issue, but with 100+ files the load time is really getting up there. So, time to introduce [r.js optimization](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js)! I use node and r.js to create a combined file, and change `data-main="main"` to `data-main="_build/main"`.

I get the following error:

> Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: (the entire body of crossroads.js)

Thoughts:

- There are [no manual / out-of-band define() calls or anonymous modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch). Everything goes through the optimizer into this one file.
- This isn't even our file - it's [crossroads.min.js](http://millermedeiros.github.com/crossroads.js/), which Require is able to handle just fine when the optimizer isn't involved.

I am still digging, but hoping someone can save me some time here.

Comment: crossroads uses an unnamed define, how are you loading/bundling it? did you specify a "paths" config pointing to it?

also if you do a r.js build I would use the source file not the minified dist file, since it will help debugging and you can easily track changes.

Comment: @MillerMedeiros yes, there is a paths member 'crossroads': 'lib/crossroads'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Use the unminified version of crossroads.js, since you are doing a r.js build it will already compress the source file.

crossroads uses an unnamed define and is wrapped into a custom [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd/) (universal module definition). The minified version won't work well since r.js can't add the proper module name.

before minification:

```
(function(define){define(["signals"], ...
```

after minification:

```
(function(a){a(["signals"], ...
```

r.js can't figure out what `a` means, it only looks for `define` calls.

Comment: just a FIY crossroads@0.12.0 won't have this issue. just pushed it to github and npm. cheers.